# PHP Fastest Pagination

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I have a MYSQL query that returns around 10,000 rows which is used mainly for reporting.

My current pagination code loads all the rows and then cuts them down to whatever the limit per page is which takes ages to load.

I am also using jquery tablesorter to help users sort the results.

Is there a way not to load all rows and make the page load time quicker?

Comment: Yes, the `limit` clause.

Comment: @meagar will limit work with tablesorter?

Comment: built your own with PHP,Mysql and AJAX, there are lots of example available on the net.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$start = 130;
$item_per_page = 10;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM whatever LIMIT $start, $item_per_page";
```

If you want to use tablesorter, there's an [AJAX example](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html). Prepare HTML code inside your pagination code, and return only the data piece of page, you can dynamically insert data when necessary.